# Consulta Entity Framework com Inner Join e Where

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou fazendo um consulta usando inner join de algumas tabelas e um where com somente uma condição, mas os dados não são retornados no EF,a mesma consulta no Mysql funciona e retorna dados.

Segue o código:

```
string raAluno = acr.getAlunoLogado().ToString();
            var aluno = (from al in neEAD.mot_aluno
                               join ta in neEAD.mot_turmaaluno on al.al_id equals ta.ta_al_id
                               join tm in neEAD.mot_turma on ta.ta_tm_id equals tm.tm_id
                               join mo in neEAD.mot_modulo on tm.tm_mod_id equals mo.mod_id
                               join dp in neEAD.mot_disciplina on mo.mod_id equals dp.dp_mod_id
                               where (al.al_ra == "'" + raAluno + "'")
                               select new IndexModel
                               {
                             ID = al.al_id,
                             Nome = al.al_nome,
                             Disciplina = dp.dp_descricao,
                             IDDisciplina = dp.dp_id,
                         }).ToString();
            return View(aluno);
```

Alguem pode me ajudar com isso, pois não consigo ver a query sql para verificar se esta correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize `ToList()` ao invés do `ToString()` *ou mesmo retire esse método*.

O `LINQ` lhe retorna um `IEnumerable` / `IQueryable`, e não uma `string`.

[Introdução a consultas LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx)

```
var aluno = (from al in neEAD.mot_aluno
                   join ta in neEAD.mot_turmaaluno on al.al_id equals ta.ta_al_id
                   join tm in neEAD.mot_turma on ta.ta_tm_id equals tm.tm_id
                   join mo in neEAD.mot_modulo on tm.tm_mod_id equals mo.mod_id
                   join dp in neEAD.mot_disciplina on mo.mod_id equals dp.dp_mod_id
                   where (al.al_ra == "'" + raAluno + "'")
                   select new IndexModel
                   {
                 ID = al.al_id,
                 Nome = al.al_nome,
                 Disciplina = dp.dp_descricao,
                 IDDisciplina = dp.dp_id,
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: mudei para .ToList() e retirei do where as aspas simples e duplas, assim funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez o seu problema seja as aspas simples na comparação e o ToString no retorno do linq, onde imagino que você queira o primeiro objeto retornado. Tente com o código abaixo:

```
string raAluno = acr.getAlunoLogado().ToString();
        var aluno = (from al in neEAD.mot_aluno
                           join ta in neEAD.mot_turmaaluno on al.al_id equals ta.ta_al_id
                           join tm in neEAD.mot_turma on ta.ta_tm_id equals tm.tm_id
                           join mo in neEAD.mot_modulo on tm.tm_mod_id equals mo.mod_id
                           join dp in neEAD.mot_disciplina on mo.mod_id equals dp.dp_mod_id
                           where (al.al_ra == raAluno)
                           select new IndexModel
                           {
                         ID = al.al_id,
                         Nome = al.al_nome,
                         Disciplina = dp.dp_descricao,
                         IDDisciplina = dp.dp_id,
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(aluno);
```