# Duvida de Trazer um Details de duas Tabelas MVC5 EntityFramework 6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Estou estudando `ASP.NET MVC5` para a faculdade, e me deparei com um problema, possuo três tabelas: `Usuario`, `PessoaFisica`, `Endereco`.

O meu problema é o seguinte, quando eu logo no sistema, consigo trazer somente as informações (`Details`) do usuário, que é e-mail e senha.

Gostaria de trazer também as informações da `PessoaFisica` e `Endereco`, que tem conexão com esta tabela a partir da `FK usu_id`.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Meu código até o momento é este no `Controller`

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    Usuario usuario = db.Usuario.Find(id);
    if (usuario != null)
    {
        Informacao inf = new Informacao();
        inf.Email = usuario.Email;
        inf.Senha = usuario.Senha;
        //Falta Tabela de Endereço e Pessoa Física
        return View(inf);

    }
    return View();
}
```

Eu pensei colocar depois do `inf.Senha` um:

```
Endereco end = db.Endereco..Where(x => usu.Id == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Depois repetir e pegar as informações da `PessoaFísica`, porém acho que não é o melhor caminho.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz ou um norte?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma entidade que possua os detalhes que queira exibir (Usuário, Pessoa e endereço) e depois popular essa entidade com uma consulta usando  [Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq). Já tem um exemplo de algo parecido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129835/consulta-entity-framework-com-inner-join-e-where).

Somente fique atendo a maneira que você constrói suas consultas. Pode acontecer da consulta ficar com um desempenho ruim. Confira a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq) para evitar esses cenários.

Comment: Não sei como está seu tempo, mas seria bom tentar criar uma camada para não deixar suas consultas e validações na sua controller.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade isso acontece por causa do Lazy Loading que, por padrão, é habilitado no EF. Lazy Loading é utilizado para que apenas os dados requisitados sejam carregados, logo, qualquer relação é ignorada ao menos que seja explicitamente requisitada. Para contornar isso você pode seguir exemplo mostrado na própria [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/querying/related-data)

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ToList();
}
```